# No IP for host ethernet when network bridging with netplan

Tags: networking, 20.04, netplan, network-bridge, xrdp

I used netplan on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop and used a yaml file like the one on this website:

https://webby.land/2018/04/27/bridging-under-ubuntu-18-04/

However, my host doesn't have a ip now? How can I fix this problem? I can still ping out and receive connections, but I can not use xrdp since I don't know what IP to use to connect.

Comment: Since you have a working network connection, it doesn;t seem like a problem. Look at the output of `ip addr`. Your IP address should be the br0 interface (or equivalent) now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bridges are interfaces on the host; because you've added the ethernet device to the bridges, it's normal and correct that the addresses are assigned to the bridge interface and not to the ethernet interface, but these addresses should be reachable as normal from the network.